# Assignunique id to each block of a Pyramid using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I came across this link: http://jsfiddle.net/Q8KUS/20/ and i was wondering if there is a way i can assign each block of this pyramid a unique id instead of giving each row the same id?

I tried changing this line:

```
strBlocksHTML += '<div class="buildingBlock"></div>';
```

to this line:

```
strBlocksHTML += '<div class="buildingBlock" id=myId'+i+' ></div>';
```

But by using this each row has the same id. Instead of having a unique number for each row  i would like to have an unique number for each block.
Could anyone help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're close, and since each row has a unique number and each block within a row will have a unique number, just combine the two, so the easiest way would be to do something like this:

```
strBlocksHTML += '<div class="buildingBlock" id="'+i+n+'"></div>';
```

The top block will have an ID of `00`, next row will have `10` and `11`, next row will have `20` `21` `22`, etc.

http://jsfiddle.net/1qj9oq2a/